# mod-mono-server4.exe using 100% of CPU on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: apache-2.4, mono, long-polling

I have an ASP.NET application that uses some long polling magic.

The problem comes when the server has accepted some requests and it's just waiting to return them. If I restart apache in that moment I get multiple instances of mod-mono-server4.exe that together use 100% of the CPU. It stays in that state until you restart the Ubuntu instance.

I can't replicate it consistently, it happens 1 in any 10-20 attempts and it happens in production too.

Does anybody know what the problem may be?